# How can I get optional object properties passed in entityAdapter.getInitialState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I initialized the state of entityAdapter and declared selectors as

```
export const devicesAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Device>({
})

export const initialDevicesState = devicesAdapter.getInitialState({
  listLoading: false,
  actionsLoading: false,
  totalCount: 0,
  groups: [] as Group[],
  deviceForEdit: null as Device,
  error: null,
});

export const {
  selectAll: selectAllDevices,
  selectById: selectDeviceById,
  selectIds: selectDeviceIds,
  selectEntities: selectDeviceEntities,
} = devicesAdapter.getSelectors((state: RootState) => state.devices);
```

Now, in an Action created with createAsyncThunk, I'm trying to access the current state of groups in my store as

```
const groups=store.getState().devices.groups;
```

Which is not working yet and I think it's a bad approach to access the state from root store component?

**Is there a better way to access groups state from devices level like using selectors of devicesAdapter?**

Comment: Do u think passing groups attribute as a payload when ever you call that action creator is considered a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple to get the store state when using createAsyncThunk using getState() method of thunkAPI, which is the default second parameter to [async payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)